# Chrome Driver failed to load on Win XP

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

This is a very strange issue I got recently with Selenium Chrome Driver V2.26. The Selenium automation testing code through Google Chrome is working excellent on Win-7 + machines. But when we deploy the code on Win-XP, it is giving strange issue. Please find below the screenshot when I try to double click the Chrome driver on XP machine:-

[image: Win XP Chrome driver issue]

Still I am unable to conclude is it a system issue or with Chrome driver as for precautionary measures I am using the latest one. Shall I downgrade for XP or any other issue I have missed?

Comment: I don't think chrome supports xp anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows XP and solved it by downloading Windows Driver Kit Version 7.1.0 (which works under Windows XP).
Download link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11800

Then you need to install just the debugging tools (select that from the list of things to install). Once install, go to the install folder (default is C:\WinDDK) and copy dbghelp.dll over to where you have chromedriver.exe. Chromedriver should then use the new dbghelp.dll and it will work. However, in my case, there was another problem in KERNEL32.dll, but that's another story...